# Ejecutar dos eventos ajax - js

Tags: javascript, ajax

Buen día foro.

Tengo una pregunta, como puedo hacer para poder ejercutar dos eventos con javascript y ajax.

```
 function validar(){
     $(document).ready(function(){
           $(document).on('submit','#addproduct',function(){
                  var data = $(this).serialize();
                  $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url:'index.php?view=addreceipt',
                    data: new FormData(this),
                    contentType: false,
                    cache: false,
                    processData: false,
                    success:function(data){
                     $('#result').html(data).fadeIn();
                    $('#result').html(data);
                    }
                  });
                  return false;
                });
              });
    }
```

El códigos anterior me ingresa mis registros. Y dispongo de este otro que me realiza una consulta y me muestra el folio. Pero lo que quiero es ejecutar los dos en mi misma función(validar), donde se ejecute primero el del agregar registros (primer código) y posteriormente el del folio (segundo código) ya requiero el ultimo folio que se ingreso en el  código 1. Espero haberme dado a entender.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#addproduct').on('submit',function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
  $.get('./?action=generatefolio',$('#addproduct').serialize(),function(data){
   $('#folio').val(data);
    });
      $('#folio').val(data);
   });
});
```

Comment: Yo no lo he entendido bien la verdad (discúlpame). Entiendo que quieres añadir una receta (registro) que te devuelve un true o un false, no? Y luego quieres además realizar un ajax que te devuelva la lista de registros actualizada y mostrarla, correcto?

Comment: ¿Hola? ¿Ever, lograste hacer funcionar tu escensario?